# Data Mining KNN Classifier

Tags: database, algorithm, data-mining, knn

Suppose a data analyst working for an insurance company was asked to build a predictive model for predicting whether a customer will buy a mobile home insurance policy. S/he tried kNN classifier with different number of neighbours (k=1,2,3,4,5). S/he got the following F-scores measured on the training data: (1.0; 0.92; 0.90; 0.85; 0.82). Based on that the analyst decided to deploy kNN with k=1. Was it a good choice? How would you select an optimal number of neighbours in this case?

Comment: As it stands, this just looks like homework

Comment: @user3195317 This might be a week late, but *SO is NOT the place to ask for homework!* Please dont to that ! Read the *How to ask page* next time!

Comment: @user3195317 If you would improve your question according to the guidelines and I think it *could* deserve an answer. Next time you ask a question, don't just ignore the rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to select a parameter of a prediction algorithm using the whole training set as the result will be biased towards this particular training set and has no information about generalization performance (i.e. performance towards unseen cases). You should apply a cross-validation technique e.g. 10-fold cross-validation to select the best K (i.e. K with largest F-value) within a range. 
This involves splitting your training data in 10 equal parts retain 9 parts for training and 1 for validation. Iterate such that each part has been left out for validation. If you take enough folds this will allow you as well to obtain statistics of the F-value and then you can test whether these values for different K values are statistically significant.

See e.g. also:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Falg_knn_training_crossvalidation.htm

The subtlety here however is that there is likely a dependency between the number of data points for prediction and the K-value. So If you apply cross-validation you use 9/10 of the training set for training...Not sure whether any research has been performed on this and how to correct for that in the final training set. Anyway most software packages just use the abovementioned techniques e.g. see SPSS in the link.
A solution is to use leave-one-out cross-validation (each data samples is left out once for testing) in that case you have N-1 training samples(the original training set has N).